# Flash: Movie stops execution of AS (maybe rendering also?) when it doesn't have focus

Tags: actionscript-3, tabs, flash-cs5

I have two flash movies, on different tabs of a user's browser.

They use LocalConnection to talk to each other, but the one on the tab which isn't active doesn't do anything until you switch back to that tab, can you change this? Maybe in the embed tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that Adobe changed about the Flash player after 10.1, in order to make it consume less CPU cycles was to force the player to only execute at 2fps (or some other ridiculously low amount) when the swf is no longer in focus (or even if it's still "in focus" but not being rendered to the screen by virtue of being in a section of the browser window that's scrolled offscreen.

I'm not aware of anything inherent to the new Flash player that would prevent LocalConnection from working, though.  Do you have listeners set up to detect whether the swfs in question are active or not before they attempt to make any calls?

Comment: Is it possible to keep it from changing the FPS? It's a 3D engine I got and when you lower the FPS for a long time animations start to build up, because AS is still running, and when you go back to it the animations start again and theres a billion of them for it to do to get back on track, sometimes so many you need to just refresh the entire page to regain control of the movie.

Comment: No, you aren't allowed to set the framerate in these instances.  There's a hack where if a stream sound (on the timeline) is playing that the rendering only drops to 8fps, and if an flv is playing only to 12fps (not sure on the precise fps numbers here, without looking back at the paperwork).  This however is probably not what you want.   Are your updates based on elapsed time, or based simply on number enter_frame events?  It sounds to me like the latter... you should instead do the former where motions, events, animations are based off of delta time rather than X number of updates.